# Custom Fonts User Script: Revert or Improve the Font Updates

Tags: script, design

Recently, Stack Exchange decided to [switch to system fonts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021?cb=1). For those of you who prefered the old appearance, or would like a different font to appear in code blocks or across the site as a whole, Custom Fonts is a user script I wrote this morning to allow just that.

#### Features

Custom Fonts allows rules to be set for different sites, which can specify a sans serif, serif, and monospace font. A default can also be specified, allowing you to choose between sans serif and serif for any site.

Custom Fonts initially doesn't change anything (unless you download one with a preset), but on lines 26 and 27 are rules that revert all of Stack Exchange to its original fonts (once un-commented). Custom rules can be written, and there is a short reference in the comments under the `Rules` object.

#### Download

Custom Fonts is a user script, meaning that it requires Greasemonkey (Firefox or browsers that support Firefox extensions) or Tampermonkey (Chrome or browsers that support Chrome extensions) to be installed.

**[Custom Fonts 1.2.4](https://github.com/RedwolfPrograms/userscripts/raw/main/custom-fonts.user.js)**

**[Custom Fonts 1.2.4, with original fonts](https://gist.github.com/RedwolfPrograms/35c237ee02015b60d643f61a6f2570a1/raw/411d70cf08dca4c6d21003cad81915ca698bcf78/custom-fonts-1.2.4-arial.user.js)**

**[Custom Fonts 1.2.4, with Roboto + Roboto Mono](https://gist.github.com/RedwolfPrograms/6587a7fb499a43e72d4ec24f4dc42df0/raw/296fcf46451326b13aa26a534fbf2623758c0ff7/custom-fonts-1.2.4-roboto.user.js)**

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm thinking about writing a post for a request for this to be in our preferences, because I much preferred the old fonts.  This looks... weird.

Comment: Usually, I think these things go a.) on StackApps, and perhaps b.) get linked in an answer to the announcement post. I've never seen them get their own question before, hence me asking before unilaterally moderating it...Sure, more people will find it here, but like Mast said that's not a reason to be off-topic :P I don't post my IPS questions on SO just because there's more people checking SO!

Comment: Thank you soooo much! This helps my eyes - I just can't read the light font the new update provided.

Comment: Can you split this in a question and an self-answer? People get confused that it is all in one.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell - I honestly think this should go in the main announcement so that people can more easily revert this awful font.

Comment: @rene Not sure about that, seems like it'd be _more_ confusing to do it that way IMO

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms You're genius! Finally I can have the nice serif font back which was tragically lost in the Great Undesign of 2018, in which a lot of sites lost their custom design!

Comment: I made a [lightweight version](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/blob/main/scripts/stackexchange-old-font/script.js) with 3 lines.

Comment: @Spectric There's a reason it's longer than that. There are lots of things that skips.

Comment: For the record, any solutions written in JS tend to be somewhat slow and have a startup delay. This is absolute overkill compared to using [a userstyle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407558/6296561) (which also loads substantially faster)

Comment: @Zoe I would recommend using a userstyle over this if you have the option, though this script is designed to (ideally) load the new CSS almost instantly (uses `@run-at document-start`) so there shouldn't be a visible delay very often. A lot more people have userscript managers installed than userstyle ones, so I figured this would be useful to share, at least as a temporary solution.

Comment: Hi! Version 1.2.2 doesn't work in GreaseMonkey in FF because of `@match        https://stackexchange.com`. This line wasn't there in 1.2.1, which does work fine.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Will fix. I also need to add `@exclude`s for chat and the API

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Fixed

Comment: When running at `document-start` the `<head>` and `<body>` elements will commonly not yet exist. The element which is guaranteed to exist and to which you can `.appendChild` is the `document.documentElement`. However, given that using `document.documentElement.appendChild` at that time will result in your `<style>` being before the `<head>` in the document, you will need to make sure that the CSS rules have a higher specificity than the ones you're wanting to replace, because they will be before, not after, any rules in CSS provided by the page. (continued)

Comment: You can easily increase the specificity by just prefixing each selector with a `body` or `html`. For those two elements, `body` and `html`, you can add a `:not(.withSomeMadeUpClassWhichWillNeverExistInTheDocumentOnThatElement)`. Using the `document.documentElement` is significantly superior to waiting for the `DOMContentLoaded` event. If you wait for `DOMContentLoaded`, which is going to be the case most of the time, depending on userscript manager, browser, and OS, the user will experience a flash of the incorrectly formatted content.

Comment: Note that you can get more complex and use a `MutationObserver` to wait for the `<head>` and/or `<body>` to be created, but that approach really isn't justified for something like this (and didn't work in the older versions of Edge).

Comment: hello; Personally, I have set myself the task of creating an extension and I have managed to customize some aspects of the site, one of them is the color of the links and the font, Here are two examples: [Main Web](https://i.imgur.com/FOvxvfN.png) and [code with fira code fonts and ligatures](https://i.imgur.com/mOO2sOM.png)